# Javascript, target.id and event.srcElement.id

Tags: javascript

i am trying to understand part of javascript code is refer to the code is:[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xHue9/1/), now there is 2 more css files the first contain(sansStyle.css):

```
body, p, td, ol, ul, select, span, div, input {
    font: .9em/1.1em verdana, geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

the second contain(serifStyle.css):

```
  body, p, td, ol, ul, select, span, div, input {
        font: 1.1em/1.2em Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    }
```

my problem is only at a small part at the javascript code that i dont understand, if you take a look at the link and at the javascript part the is:

```
if (inVal) {
        if (typeof inVal == "string") {
            title = inVal;
        }
        else {
            title = inVal.target.id;
        }
    }
    else {
        title = window.event.srcElement.id;
    }
```

now i do understand that we refer at the else to the id becouse it got the same value as the title value we need, but the problem is that if its not a string so what is it? and how does it get for example inVal.target.id what is inVal.target is?, and about the window event.srcElement.id what event is it? if can some one please help me understand thoes two i will be very thankful.

Comment: can you post the code that defines inVal?/the whole function? Just to give you a start, `inVal.target.id` would mean that `inVal` was a `DOM event`[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events)

Comment: I recommend to go through these excellent articles: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: long time ago i was studying javascript and i have learned it but now i come back and i do remember this really good site thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inVal can be two things it can be a String or it can be a click event.

1.) inVal can be a string when it gets the title (which is the style I assume) see this line `setActiveStylesheet(title)`

If you look closely title will always be a string either form the cookie `var thisCookie = cookieVal("style");` or from the **getActiveStylesheet()** function

2.) inVal can be a click event as Haynar pointed it out looks at

```
allButtons[i].onclick = setActiveStylesheet;
```

Hence you check if it is a string

```
    if (typeof inVal == "string") {
        title = inVal; // when it comes form the cookie or getActiveStylesheet()
    }
    else {
        title = inVal.target.id; // it is an event
    }
```

**window.event** is the event property. For example **window.event.type** will give you the type of the event that took place. Like wise **window.event.srcElement** or **window.event.target** both properties return the HTML element the event took place on. **window.event.srcElement.id** is going to return the id of the event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yeshwanth Venkatesh, can you tell me please what is happen if inVal return empty what does  window.event.srcElement.id mean? and thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

inVal is the click event and the target is a DOM element on which that event has occured. If you look at this line:

```
allButtons[i].onclick = setActiveStylesheet;
```

you'll see that this function is being called when the button is clicked and the event is passed as argument to that function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer haynar, i understand that if the inVal is not a string so it return the event just occur, but i dont understand becouse if you take a look at the function getPreferredStylesheet() returning the inVal its return the title value or an empty string so how does it become an event?, and thanks again.